# trying to get the href attribute of <a> tag onclick - no errors?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

Trying to simply identify if any  tags are clicked on at anytime and get the href attribute of the clicked tag to store in the database.

**To test i'm attempting to print out the href but nothing is printing on screen  AND no errors in console? Any ideas?**

```
// Anchor Tags - Capture the href of the link clicked
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = aTags.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    aTags[i].onclick = function() {
    var aTagHref = aTags[i].getAttribute("href");
        alert(aTagHref);
    };
}
```

Comment: USe 'this' or event.target. The way you're trying to do this doesn't work because you don't cache `i` through a closure. So by the time the loop finishes, i will be aTags.length + 1 and hence all clicks will try to find a nonexisting element inside the aTags. Always try to use event.target in event handlers, since it will tell you which element the event came from without the need to cache it in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a event listener you will not have that array of elements, and also, you can use the `this` to reference the clicked `a`.

Like this:

```js
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = aTags.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    aTags[i].onclick = function() {
    var aTagHref = this.getAttribute("href");
        alert(aTagHref);
    };
}
```

```html
<a href="#asd">a</a>
<br />
<a href="#asdf">b</a>
<br />
<a href="#asdfg">c</a>
```

Comment: It works! Quick question, what is the logic behind the for loop var i = aTags.length - 1; ? Aren't we skipping the initial index by subtracting 1 from length i.e.  instead of iterating as i= 4,3,2,1 we are interating like: 3,2,1... correct?

Comment: @Shaz, the for life cicle in this case is -> create `var i = 3 - 1`; check condition; do logic; decrement; check condition.... So, the value of `i` goes like 2, 1 and 0

Comment: That's my point. It doesn't do the logic on '3'. starting out. If there are 3 links in var i, isn't it just doing the logic on 2,1 0 and NOT 3nth?

Comment: @Shaz if it starts in 3 you will get a index out of range error, the index of an array starts from 0, so... the position 0 -> a link; position 1 -> b link; position 2 -> c link; https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_element

Comment: Makes sense now. I wasn't thinking or length property as an array (stupid) instead or a variable. My bad. Thanks for explaining!